# Outsourcing the root template into a TYPO3 extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I created my own site package and thus the complete configuration into my own EXT. outsourced.

Now I have included in the database a template on the root page around the StaticTemplate of the EXT installed by me. and manage it.

Can this be outsourced to the site package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to achieve that:

1. Export the template and place it in the folder Initialisation/data.xml of your sitepackage see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/CreateNewDistribution/Index.html#database-data
2. Instead of placing your template into the database you can include your TypoScript without a sys_template record explained here https://usetypo3.com/did-you-know.html#c554